# Bounds on the diagonal elements of inverse of negative definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ negative definite matrix such that $X_{ii}<0$ for all $i$ and $X_{ij}\geq 0$ for $i\neq j$. Denote by $Y=X^{-1}$ the inverse of $X$. I would like to find bounds on the diagonal elements of $Y$. Can we find $\underline{Y}$ and $\overline{Y}$ such that $\underline{Y}\leq Y_{ii} \leq \overline{Y}$ for all $i$?

Note that $-X$ satisfies the definition of an [$M$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix) and so its inverse is such that all its elements are nonnegative. This implies that all the elements of $Y$ are nonpositive and so one potential upper bound is $\overline{Y}=0$ but I would like to find a tighter bound if possible.

Also, in the special in which $X$ is diagonal, it is easy to show that
$$
\left(\max_i X_{ii}\right)^{-1}\leq Y_{ii} \leq \left(\min_i X_{ii}\right)^{-1}.
$$
I am hoping that a result like this extends to nondiagonal $X$'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Rayleigh quotient. For any hermitian matrix $A$ and nonzero vector $x$,
$$\lambda_{\min}(A) \leq \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} \leq \lambda_{\max}(A).$$
By taking $x=e_i$, the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector (with a $1$ at position $i$ and zeros everywhere else), you obtain:
$$\lambda_{\min}(X^{-1}) \leq (X^{-1})_{ii} \leq \lambda_{\max}(X^{-1}).$$
You have $\lambda_{\min}(X^{-1}) = 1/\lambda_{\max}(X)$ and $\lambda_{\max}(X^{-1}) = 1/\lambda_{\min}(X)$ since all eigenvalues are negative, and since if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X$ then $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X^{-1}$ (if $Xv = \lambda v$ then $X^{-1}v = (1/\lambda)v$).

Comment: This only works if "negative definite" implies symmetric in this context

Comment: To generalize this to the alternative definition of definiteness, one should consider the eigenvalues of $(A + A^T)/2$ instead of those of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, I'll copy some ideas from [my earlier post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/989748/81360).

Let $s$ be equal to the absolute value of the smallest (most negative) diagonal entry of $X$.  We can rewrite $X$ as
$X = A - sI$,
where $A$ is a non-negative matrix.

By the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), $A$ must have a positive eigenvalue equal to $\rho(A)$.
Furthermore, for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $\lambda - s$ is an eigenvalue of $X$.  Thus, $\rho(A) - s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  Since the eigenvalues of $X$ all have negative real part, we note that
$$
\text{Re}(\rho(A) - s) > 0 \implies \rho(A) < s
$$
So, we have $\rho(A) < s$.  Denote $B = \frac 1s A$.
We note that $\rho(B) = \rho(A)/s < 1$. Let $X' = \frac 1s X = B - I$.  Since $\rho(B) < 1$, we can show that the infinite series $-\sum_{n \geq 0} B^n$ converges to $(B-I)^{-1}$.  With that established, we have
$$
X^{-1} = [sX']^{-1} = -s^{-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n = -s^{-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(I + \frac 1s X\right)^n.
$$
From there, one could apply the ideas from [this recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3972956/81360) (with the same asker as this one). In particular, let $v$ denote a Perron eigenvector of $B$ (i.e. $v > 0$ and $Bv = \rho(B)v$). Let $D = \operatorname{diag}(v)$. We see that $D^{-1}BD$ is a matrix with constant row-sum, and that
$$
X^{-1} = -s^{-1} D\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty (D^{-1}BD)^n\right]D^{-1}.
$$